# Why is the default group of Git files in Windows is 197121?

Tags: linux, windows, git, mingw-w64

Under Windows, Git (MINGW64) assigns a default group to a file: 197121 (PS: if you search this number on the Internet, you will find that most of the problems are related to Git). I wonder if this group (or number) has any meaning?

```sh
ls - al

drwxr-xr-x 1 Zhang 197121 0 August 18 09:46 file.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the group "None".
As explained in [this thread](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2015-04/msg00532.html)

> When you ask the Windows GUI for the ACL of a file,
> it knows whom to ask for the SIDs.  It's either a SID it knows anyway
> (builtin, SAM, AD), or it asks the underlying server of the share.

> However, the account handling in Cygwin is decoupled from the code
> fetching file ACLs.  It ony generically cares for passwd and group
> entries, and it only knows to ask SAM or AD for the SID.  It has no
> connection to the server serving the share.  This *might* be possible,
> but code for that just isn't there.

[Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461435/why-is-the-default-group-of-git-files-in-windows-is-197121/63461988?noredirect=1#comment112243055_63461988):

> ### how "S-1-5-21--513" (None) is mapped to the GID value 197121:
>
> ```
> Group=S-1-5-21-XXX-513(WINDOWS\None) (gid=197121)
> ```
>
> The hex value `0x30201` provides some insight, since `0x201` is `513`, but I don't know where `0x30` comes from.
> It also helps to know that the access token for most users in Windows sets "`None`" as the default group for new objects (i.e. [`TokenPrimaryGroup`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/windowsidentity.cs,478c4d53d81557d4,references)).
>
> Windows access checks don't use the object's group directly (unlike Cygwin), but an entry for the group will be added to the DACL of an object if its parent container has an inheritable entry for "`CREATOR GROUP`" (`S-1-3-1`).
>
> The lower part equal to `0x0201` is explained as the RID value `DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_USERS` for group "`None`" (aka "`Domain Users`" if the machine is attached to a domain), assuming they're only using the lower 16 bits of 32-bit RID values, but I'm still curious where the initial 3 comes from in `0x30201`.
> Similarly, for the first assigned user SID "`S-1-5-21-<MACHINE ID>-1001`", the Cygwin UID is `0x303E9`, which has the same leading `0x3`.

See also "[How to use native "Active Directory Services Interface" (ADSI) components to find the primary group](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321360/how-to-use-native-adsi-components-to-find-the-primary-group)":

> The primary group of a user is stored (as the group's RID in the user's domain) on the `PrimaryGroupID` attribute of a user object.
>
> A user's primary group can only be a group that exists in the same domain as the user, and this group has to be a group that the user is a member of.
>
> Also, this Group object in the Active Directory has an attribute called **`PrimaryGroupToken`**, which stores the RID for this group within the domain.

[This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ad1396f1-a951-4a28-9a35-e2c5d9a2b22f/finding-primary-group-of-users-in-ad?forum=winserverDS) adds:

> The integer 513 is value of the `primaryGroupToken` attribute of the group "`Domain Users`".
> All users whose `primaryGroupID` is 513 have this group designated as their primary.

This is related to [security identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#what-are-security-identifiers), as [seen here](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/issues/204#issuecomment-441834853):

> ### SID
>
> S-1-5-domain-513
>
> ### Display Name
>
> Domain Users
>
> ### Description
>
> A global group that includes all users in a domain.
> When you create a new User object in Active Directory, the user is automatically added to this group.

This [thread references](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Numeric-group-IDs-for-system-groups-tp140862p140866.html):

- "[Mapping Windows SIDs to POSIX uid/gid values](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-how)"
- "[Well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids?redirectedfrom=MSDN)"
- "[Security Identifier (SID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)"

> Cygwin id 197121 == RID 513 == 0x201 - in range of reserved RIDs < 1000.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The quote and link explains little about how "S-1-5-21-<MACHINE ID>-513" (None) is mapped to the GID value 197121. The hex value 0x30201 provides some insight, since 0x201 is 513, but I don't know where 0x30 comes from. It also helps to know that the access token for most users in Windows sets "None" as the default group for new objects (i.e. `TokenPrimaryGroup`). Windows access checks don't use the object's group directly (unlike Cygwin), but an entry for the group will be added to the DACL of an object if its parent container has an inheritable entry for "CREATOR GROUP" (S-1-3-1).

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer and added more references to try and tie Windows SID "None" to Cygwin gid 197121.

Comment: The lower part equal to 0x0201 is explained as the RID value `DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_USERS` for group "None" (aka "Domain Users" if the machine is attached to a domain), assuming they're only using the lower 16 bits of 32-bit RID values, but I'm still curious where the initial 3 comes from in 0x30201. Similarly, for the first assigned user SID "S-1-5-21-<MACHINE ID>-1001", the Cygwin UID is 0x303E9, which has the same leading 0x3.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you again. Some questions remain indeed.